# How to check if a php script is being called by another script on the server?

Tags: php

I have a script scripty.php

Sometimes this script gets called through the browser.

Other times it gets called by another script on the server.

How can I (securely) check within scripty.php to see whether or not it is being called by the server?

Comment: How does the script get called exactly from the server? Using include()? file_get_contents()? Using a file path or a http URL?

Comment: @Pekka - in the form of an http URL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> in the form of an http URL

The `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` variable that gives you the IP address of the client who made the request should be  `127.0.0.1` when the script is called from the server.

Comment: Unless it is called from another script, that is from the browser... I understood it that way.

Comment: @Rok if a script on the server is making a `http://` call, that script will be the caller, not the browser. At least that's how I understand what the OP was saying in the comment

Comment: I meant script a.php is called from http:// and calls another script b.php. Therefore b.php `script is being called by another script on the server`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not suitable for the development on local machine. You'll get `127.0.0.1` either way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7225638/535406 is seems to be a good solution relying only on script _names_ — no additional constants or variables required.

Comment: @jibiel that won't tell you whether the request was made by the browser or by a server, though. You could use the HTTP_USER_AGENT for that in your scenario - it's the browser name and it's going to differ when you make a request from server side using curl or fopen

Comment: Is it not good to set some session variable when new request come? and cross check when request arises for a particular script.

Answer (score 6):

you can create a variable before including your script

```
$by_script = true;
include("new_script.php");
```

and check it inside

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: You want to know, if the script its called trough a browser, or from CLI

```
var_dump(PHP_SAPI);
```

Comment: Yeah, maybe OP wanted it your way. It is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

On any script that will be calling it define a constant like `define("IN_SCRIPT")` and within scripty.php you can check for the constant to determine if it's inside another script or not.

e.g.

```
if(defined("IN_SCRIPT")){
// We must be inside a script right now!
}
```

or

```
if(!defined("IN_SCRIPT")){
// We are working alone now
}
```

Answer (score 1):

consider a file named test.php, this is the only code contained:

```
echo str_replace("\\","/",$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
echo str_replace("\\","/",__FILE__);
```

when a user execute* test.php by browser url, this is the output:

```
"C:/xampp/htdocs/test.php"
"C:/xampp/htdocs/test.php"
```

otherwise, differ (( in this case another.php was executed by browser url, who include test.php ))

```
"C:/xampp/htdocs/another.php"
"C:/xampp/htdocs/test.php"
```