# Check if php script was called by the server or remotely in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cron, superglobals

I have a crontab php script that resides in one of the folders on abc.tld.
The problem is that the script could also be fired by calling it directly (i.e. http://abc.tld/crontab.php)
To eliminate such possibility, I assume, I could do something like

```
if( isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) || isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) )
     die( 'Never gonna happen!' );
```

But what is the right way? (except .htaccess)

Crontab entry:

```
0 12 * * 1  /usr/local/bin/php /home/pavellebedev/public_html/abc.tld/wp-content/plugins/easy-timesheet/kernel/cron/ezts_timesheet_notifications.php
```

Comment: good god man, disable that file all together, or put it above public root and call with php that way. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a php script only from Cron or check if request from cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702472/run-a-php-script-only-from-cron-or-check-if-request-from-cron)

Comment: @ATechGuy, no can do. Must be within abc.tld.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    // Called from command-line, maybe cron
} elseif(php_sapi_name() == 'apache2handler') {
    // Called from the apache2 webserver upon web request
}
```

Documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

Answer (score 1):

As a conclusion of my research extended from Calimero's answer, here's the most reliable way to make sure that the script was called by crontab (php 5.3+):

```
if( stripos(php_sapi_name(), 'cgi') === false || stripos(php_sapi_name(), 'cli') === false ) die('Not cron');
```

Comment: Could you by chance post the crontab entry in your question ? Your answer only makes sense if you are running CGI php as CLI (it is possible, although slightly inconvenient), or if the cron job is a curl request to the webserver happening to run CGI php. I discarded those cases too soon, I'd be delighted to update my answer acordingly.

Comment: just did, my sapi returns cgi_fcgi

Comment: Actually experiment has shown that you right, @Calimero, Php.net must have got it wrong (?) I have edited my answer as calling the script by another non-cron script on server side results in "cgi"

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate [How to check if a php script is being called by another script on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312086/how-to-check-if-a-php-script-is-being-called-by-another-script-on-the-server)

The answer :

The `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` variable that gives you the IP address of the client who made the request should be `127.0.0.1` when the script is called from the server.

Comment: wrong. `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` is not set when a php script is run through CLI.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was only thinking about the possibility that the php file was intended only for web use, my bad

Comment: Don't copy/paste answers from other questions. If you find a question that answers this one, this should be marked as a duplicate instead (and if you don't have rep to mark it as a duplicate, just leave a comment about it instead).

Comment: Why did someone up vote this? It's wrong since it doesn't answer the question, nor should anyone copy/paste answers from other posts.