# Check if a file was included or loaded

Tags: php

Is there any elegant way to check if a file was included by using `include`/`include_once`/`require`/`require_once` or if the page was actually loaded directly? I'm trying to set up a testing file inside class files while I'm creating them.

I'm looking for something similar to Python's `if __name__ == "__main__":` technique. Without setting globals or constants.

Comment: Think have found a way .... hold on

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397004/php-check-if-a-file-is-loaded-directly-instead-of-including

Comment: This question is a bit ambiguous. if you want to know if a **different** file (from the current file) was already loaded: `if(in_array(__DIR__ . '/path/to/file.php', get_included_files())){ echo __DIR__ . '/path/to/file.php was already loaded'; }`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Quoted from: [How to know if php script is called via require_once()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545878/how-to-know-if-php-script-is-called-via-require-once)

> I was looking for a way to determine if a file have been included or called directly, all from within the file. At some point in my quest I passed through this thread. Checking various other threads on this and other sites and pages from the PHP manual I got enlightened and came up with this piece of code:

```
if (basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])) {
  echo "called directly";
} else {
  echo "included/required";
}
```

> In essence it compares if the name of the current file (the one that
>   could be included) is the same as the file that is beeing executed.

Credit: @Interwebs Cowboy

Comment: I think this breaks when both files have the same name but are in separate directories. Works fine without `basename()`.

If `/var/www/index.php` includes `/var/www/test/index.php` for example, `/var/www/test/index.php` would think it is called directly. Still, +1 because this helped me alot :)

Comment: And it doesn't work when the file is called by a cron job because you don't have $_SERVER variable...

Comment: Only voting this down because NullPoiиteя`s answer is better and should be accepted IMO.

Answer (score 29):

you can do this by [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) — Returns an array with the names of included or required files and validate against `__FILE__`

Comment: And how would I check that against what I have loaded? `/test.php` can include `/includes/test.php`

Comment: **Complete example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467334/2377343**

Comment: Does not work for me. As the documentation on get_included_files says: The script originally called is considered an "included file," so it will be listed together with the files referenced by include and family.

Answer (score 19):

I appreciate all the answers, but I didn't want to use any one's solution here, so I combined your ideas and got this:

```
<?php
    // place this at the top of the file
    if (count(get_included_files()) == 1) define ('TEST_SUITE', __FILE__);

    // now I can even include bootstrap which will include other
    // files with similar setups
    require_once '../bootstrap.php'

    // code ...
    class Bar {
        ...
    }
    // code ...

    if (defined('TEST_SUITE') && TEST_SUITE == __FILE__) {
        // run test suite here  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
if (defined('FLAG_FROM_A_PARENT'))
// Works in all scenarios but I personally dislike this

if (__FILE__ == get_included_files()[0])
// Doesn't work with PHP prepend unless calling [1] instead.

if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])
// May break on Windows due to mixed DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

if (basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
// Doesn't work with files with the same basename but different paths

if (realpath(__FILE__) == realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
// Seems to do the trick as long as document root is properly configured
```

Note: On WAMP Servers virtual-hosts sometimes inherit the default document root setting, causing `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to display wrong path.

Answer (score 7):

`get_included_files()` return array where 0 index mean first "included" file. Because direct run mean "include" in this terms, you can simple check first index for equality for `__FILE__`:

```
if(get_included_files()[0] == __FILE__){
    do_stuff();
}
```

This can not work on PHP 4, because PHP 4 not add run file in this array.

Comment: While this may solve the problem, code only answers are not encouraged on SO. It is always better to leave an explanation as to why this will solve the problem.

Comment: Please see [answer].

Comment: Your answer should explain how this solves the problem and how this improves on the existing up-voted answers that provide the same solution. Also, as this question is 5 years old and has many upvoted answers, your efforts would be more appreciated by users who have recent unanswered questions.

Comment: Despite the negative comments, I found this the best answer to the question (doesn't assume web server, doesn't loop needlessly, simple, etc). Thanks Enyby and ngmh.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
    if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])
    {
        //file was navigated to directly
    }
?>
```

Taken from mgutt's answer to a slightly different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397004/php-check-if-a-file-is-loaded-directly-instead-of-including?newreg=86b536715ee341f1a3d1bebed6993ca0). It's important to note this doesn't work if the script is run from command line but other than that it functions exactly like python's

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

as far as I can tell

Answer (score 5):

They is no way to separate them as `include/include_once/require/require_once` but php has `get_included_files` and `get_required_files` which is the same thing and only returns array of all included files. Its does not separate it if its `required` or `included`.

Example `a.php`

```
include 'b.php';
include_once 'c.php';
require 'd.php';
var_dump(get_required_files());
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string '..\lab\stockoverflow\a.php' (length=46) <---- Returns current file
  1 => string '..\lab\stockoverflow\b.php' (length=46)
  2 => string '..\lab\stockoverflow\c.php' (length=46)
  3 => string '..\lab\stockoverflow\d.php' (length=46)
```

But you can do something like

```
$inc = new IncludeManager($file);
var_dump($inc->find("b.php")); // Check if a file is included
var_dump($inc->getFiles("require_once")); // Get All  Required Once
```

Class Used

```
class IncludeManager {
    private $list = array();
    private $tokens = array();
    private $find;
    private $file;
    private $type = array(262 => "include",261 => "include_once",259 => "reguire",258 => "require_once");

    function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->_parse();
    }

    private function _parse() {
        $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($this->file));
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tokens); $i ++) {
            if (count($tokens[$i]) == 3) {
                if (array_key_exists($tokens[$i][0], $this->type)) {
                    $f = $tokens[$i + 1][0] == 371 ? $tokens[$i + 2][1] : $tokens[$i + 1][1];
                    $this->list[] = array("pos" => $i,"type" => $this->type[$tokens[$i][0]],"file" => trim($f, "\"\'"));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function find($find) {
        $finds = array_filter($this->list, function ($v) use($find) {
            return $v['file'] == $find;
        });

        return empty($finds) ? false : $finds;
    }

    public function getList() {
        return $this->list;
    }

    public function getFiles($type = null) {
        $finds = array_filter($this->list, function ($v) use($type) {
            return is_null($type) ? true : $type == $v['type'];
        });
        return empty($finds) ? false : $finds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different idea. 
Just include the file whenever you need it.
Inside the include file you can decide whether it needs to include the contents:

```
<?php
if (defined("SOME_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_THIS_FILE"))
    return;
define("SOME_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_THIS_FILE", 1);

// Rest of code goes here
```

Comment: This reminds me of the [include guard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) commonly used in C header files.

Answer (score 2):

## Working solution:

```
$target_file = '/home/path/folder/file.php'; // or use __FILE__

if ($x=function($e){return str_replace(array('\\'), '/', $e);}) if(in_array( $x($target_file), array_map( $x ,  get_included_files() ) ) )
{
    exit("Hello, already included !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `get_included_files` is the perfect solution, what if your main script included some other scripts before the check? My suggestion is to check whether `__FILE__` equals `realpath($argv[1])`:

```
<?php
require('phpunit/Autoload.php');

class MyTests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // blabla...
}

if (__FILE__ == realpath($argv[0])) {
    // run tests.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a similar approach to this issue when I cam across it. The solution I found was to load each file as needed in an include_once method. Hope this helps.

```
$FILES = get_included_files();  // Retrieves files included as array($FILE)
$FILE = __FILE__;               // Set value of current file with absolute path
if(!in_array($FILE, $FILES)){   // Checks if file $FILE is in $FILES
  include_once "PATH_TO_FILE";  // Includes file with include_once if $FILE is not found.
}
```

I have the following function established to check files loaded:

```
ARRAY_DUMP($FILES);

function ARRAY_DUMP($array){
  echo "
    <span style='font-size:12px;'>".date('h:i:s').":</span>
    <pre style='font-size:12px;'>", print_r($array, 1), "</pre>
  ";
}
```

Output:

```
currentArray
(
  [0] => /home/MY_DOMAIN/hardeen/index.php
  [1] => /home/MY_DOMAIN/hardeen/core/construct.php
  [2] => /home/MY_DOMAIN/hardeen/core/template.php
  [3] => /home/MY_DOMAIN/hardeen/bin/tags.php
  [4] => /home/MY_DOMAIN/hardeen/bin/systemFunction.php
)
```