# Executing a file only if it's included

Tags: php

How can I code a php file to execute only if the file is included. For example in this form it won't run (or will be redirected to another page):

```
www.example.com/file.php
```

And in this form it will run:

```
<?php
include 'file.php';
?>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999658/check-if-a-file-was-included-orloaded

Comment: Are you possibly looking for the solution to *store non-public files outside of the public webroot* so they can't be directly accessed by users?

Comment: Create flag ( as constant ) and check if `defined`

Comment: I didn't get the sense of "execute only if included" (if it's included as PHP file, it will be executed) - but remote files will be included as they will be processed with remote web-server. You can't get source code unless web-server treats PHP files as usual text files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a guard expression to the start of the included file, so if you have these two files:

1. included.php
2. index.php

#### index.php

```
<?php
$runningFileName = "index.php"; 
include("included.php");
?>
```

#### included.php

```
<?php 
if( empty( $runningFileName ) ) die("Cannot access this page directly");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define constant in main file and check it in included file.

index.php

```
<?php
define('IN_INDEX', true);
include __DIR__ . '/included.php';
```

included.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('IN_INDEX')) {
    redirect();
}
```