# Can I make a PHP function "private" in a script?

Tags: php

I want some functions to be not visible when `required`, but visible in the script they belong to.
For example:

required.php:

```
<?php
function privateFunction() {
    echo 'from private function\n';
}
echo 'from required.php: ';
privateFunction();
```

index.php:

```
<?php
require './required.php';
echo 'from index.php: ';
privateFunction(); // I want this to give an error like "private function called outside the script it has been declared".
```

I have already tried making the function `private`, but it only gives a parse error.

Comment: Why not using OOP?

Comment: use Class and make function private.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra
I know, but if I do that, the function won't be accessible from the "required.php" script, and I can't mark a class 'private', can I?

Comment: Or use another approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999658/check-if-a-file-was-included-or-loaded  to check if file loaded directly or thru include

Comment: dont define class private, make function public , private .. as per your need

Comment: Okay, but I want the function to be accessible ONLY from the 'required.php', and NOT from 'index.php'.

Comment: You can't make ordinary functions private. Functions are global by design. You could make something like: `$func = function () { ... }`. Then you can use it as `$func();`. That way, you can at least limit it to the scope it's written in and you can unset it when you're done with it.

Comment: If you explain to us _why_ you need this and what it's for, it's going to be _much_ easier for us to come up with a good solution. Right now, it kind of sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

required.php:

```
<?php
class A {
    private function privateFunction() {
        echo 'from private function\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need the function to be accessible from a class, but from the script.

Answer (score 0):

This is a probably a bad idea in general (see comments above), but the following should do what you're asking.

It makes use of [`debug_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to grab the file name of the function then the file name of the function's caller, and compares them. If they don't match, it throws an exception:

```
function assertCalledByCurrentScript(): void
{
  $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
  if (isset($backtrace[1]) && $backtrace[0]['file'] !== $backtrace[1]['file']) {
    throw new \BadFunctionCallException("Cannot call {$backtrace[1]['function']} from outside of its defining script.");
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
function privateFunction()
{
  assertCalledByCurrentScript();

  // rest of your "private" function here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically only option you have is to hide private stuff inside class:

```
//Your file
class MyClass
{
  public static function myAction()
  {
    $internalStuff = self::internalStuff();
    return 'Using this function you can get what is inside internalStuff: ' . $internalStuff;
  }

  private static function internalStuff()
  {
     return 'Some internal stuff not accessible from outside';
  }
}

function myAction()
{
    return MyClass::myAction();
}

//Otherfile
//require yourfile.php

//You can only use `myAction` as function
echo myAction();

//Or call
echo MyClass::myAction();

//But you cannot use `internalStuff
echo MyClass::internalStuff();
```