# Is there any way to know if the file was included or loaded directly?

Tags: php

**GetCategories.php**

```
<?php
require_once "Connection.php";

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES");
$array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    $array[] = $row;

//Execute this code only if was loaded directly
echo json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Is there any way to know if the `GetCategories.php` file was included or loaded directly?

I found a lot of similar questions but can't find any helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, bound to be a duplicate.  One way if you're not using any URL rewriting, is to check the name of the file against the file that is called.  Here's one way to do that:

```
if(basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
    //direct
} else {
    //included
}
```

1. `__FILE__` returns the actual file path on disk of the file, such as `/var/www/mysite/GetCategories.php`
2. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns the current file loaded from the webserver, such as `/includes/GetCategories.php` or `/index.php`

If they are the same, then it was loaded directly.  If they are not the same then the file from 2 above included the file from 1.

Comment: I already found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12999758/7474282) but I don't use this method because I did not understand how this method works, I hate to write in my project anything I can not understand. Do you mind explaining to me how this code works exactly?

Comment: They are easy to lookup on php.net but I added a blurb.

Comment: This doesn't work, if the main file and the included file have the same filename, e.g. the very common `index.php`.

Comment: Have you tested rewrite rules?

Comment: @Wiimm In my project, I don't think there are files in the same name, Are I still safe?

Comment: @TahaSami The solution works if all filenames are different. For my projects the names aren't unique, e.g. `list.php`  and `index.php` are used multiple times in different directories. Another problem could be redirects through e.g. .htaccess. That would have to be checked.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution.

```
$is_included = get_included_files()[0] != __FILE__;
```

`get_included_files()` returns a list of all files that were included. The very first file is always at top (index 0). If it differs from the current file (`__FILE__`), it is included.

The advantage over my other answer is that the line can be anywhere in the source code.

Again: I'm not sure what happens if different kinds of redirects are used.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the following code at the top of each relevant file, the `$is_included` tells you the state:

```
$is_included = defined('INCLUDE_GUARD');
if (!$is_included)
    define('INCLUDE_GUARD',1);
```